# Fourier series and Fourier transform of a periodic function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The Fourier coefficient $C_n$ of a periodic function $s(t)$ with period $T$ is given by

$$C_n= \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T s(t) e^{-2\pi int/T} \,dt$$

Now consider the Fourier term

$$\hat{S}\Big(\frac{n}{T}\Big)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} s(t) e^{-2\pi int/T}\,dt$$

Is the assumption that $C_n=\hat{S}\big(\frac{n}{T}\big)$ correct?

Also,  $\hat{S}\big(\frac{n}{T}\big)$ can be seen as the projection of $S(t)$ on  $e^{-2\pi int/T}$, can the same be said about $C_n$? If yes, how can we show the equivalence of $C_n$ and $\hat{S}\big(\frac{n}{T}\big)$? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be correct if you used $\chi_{[0,T]}(t)s(t)$ (where $\chi_{[0,T]}(t)$ is the box or indicator function of $[0,T]$) in the integrand. $s(t)$ itself as a periodic function is not square integrable. So the Fourier transform in the strict sense does not exist, especially not as a Fourier integral.

However, you can compute the Fourier transform in the sense of tempered distributions.

If $s(t)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}C_ne^{2\pi i\,kt/T}$, then the Fourier transform is of the shape $S(f)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}C_n\delta(f-n/T)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Just one question about the special case where $s(t)=cos(t)$ : computing the fourier transform in the sense of tempered distributions results in two dirac deltas, is it wrong to expect the same thing from $C_n$? Also, i googled a bit but i'm not sure what you mean by $\chi_{[0,T]}$...

Comment: Last first: It is one of the notations of the indicator function. And yes, you would get the delta peaks of the Fourier series.